# Which way is a better way to iterate through a dictionary and print exclusively the values?

Tags: python-3.7

I'm setting up a dictionary that provides attributes of pizza as keys and details of the attributes as values. I wanted to print all the values of the pizza. And have found two methods. One is importing OrderedDict from collections. Another is using enumerate.

Which way is the more pythonic way?

These the two ways:

Way 1:

```
from collections import OrderedDict


pizza = OrderedDict({
    "style": "New York",
    "slices": 8,
    "diameter": "15 inches",
    "toppings": ["mushrooms", "green peppers"],
    "is_tasty": True
})

for attributes in pizza.values():

    print(attributes)
```

Way 2:

```
pizza = {
    "style": "New York",
    "slices": 8,
    "diameter": "15 inches",
    "toppings": ["mushrooms", "green peppers"],
    "is_tasty": True
}

for i, attributes in enumerate(pizza):

    print(pizza[attributes])
```

Both methods result in the same output.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#the-zen-of-python)

> Explicit is better than implicit.

The Pythonic way is to use the explicit `.values()` method.

There are four ways of iterating over a dictionary:

```
[1] for key in my_dict:
        ...
[2] for key in my_dict.keys():
        ...
[3] for value in my_dict.values():
        ...
[4] for key, value in my_dict.items():
        ...
```

By definition, a dictionary consists of `key: value` pairs. When not specifying any sub-method, a dictionary will iterate over its `keys`. Alternatively, as shown above, you can also specify whether you want the `values` or the entire pairs using the `items()` function.

In your question, you use the `enumerate` function, but that does nothing to change the output of iterating over the dictionary, it only adds an index (which you don't use).

In terms of speed, there doesn't seem to be a difference between `[1]` and `[3]`, although `[4]` is clearly slower because of the extra work. (Not that those few nanoseconds really matter, but it's the thought that counts 0=)

```
In [1]: from collections import OrderedDict 
   ...:  
   ...: pizza = OrderedDict({ 
   ...:     "style": "New York", 
   ...:     "slices": 8, 
   ...:     "diameter": "15 inches", 
   ...:     "toppings": ["mushrooms", "green peppers"], 
   ...:     "is_tasty": True 
   ...: })                                                                                                                         

In [2]: %timeit for value in pizza.values(): x = value                                                                     
248 ns ± 1.78 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [3]: %timeit for key in pizza: x = pizza[key]                                                                                   
245 ns ± 1.27 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [4]: %timeit for i, key in enumerate(pizza): x = pizza[key]                                                                     
411 ns ± 0.625 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks. I see how being explicit can be preferred over implicit. The same goes for language IRL. In this specific case, though, would the weight of being explicit be greater than [3], as [3] performs faster? 3ns is not much but if scaled, it may be a considerable duration.

Comment: @peyo The speed difference is really not relevant in this case, especially on the nanosecond-scale. After all, even at *one billion* operations, a 3ns difference per operation would only be 3 seconds. One of Python's main strengths is code readability. If pure execution speed is your main concern, you probably want to port to the code to a compiled language like C(++) anyway.